# Automatic uploading a local directory all files to ftp server using php

Tags: php, ftp

I want to upload the directory content which includes only text files to a ftp server and it should be automated through windows task schedular. Right now I'm using this but its only uploading one file, My requirement is basically a user can copy its files to a specific folder and it should be uploaded on ftp server asap.
this is the code I'm using right now:

```
$host = 'ftp.xyz.com';
$usr = 'abc123';
$pwd = 'l2345';
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$date = date('d-m-Y_hi');
$name = $date.".txt";
$local_file = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Conversion/Upload/xyz/abc.txt';
$ftp_path = '/public_html/xyz/abc.txt';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");
ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);
echo (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
echo "\n";
if (!function_exists('ftp_chmod')) {
function ftp_chmod($ftp_stream, $mode, $filename){
    return ftp_site($ftp_stream, sprintf('CHMOD %o %s', $mode, $filename));
}
}
if (ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0666, $ftp_path) !== false) {
echo $ftp_path . " chmoded successfully to 666\n";
} else {
echo "could not chmod $file\n";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload multiple files, you'll want to either issue a series of FTP (connections and) transfers with a loop in your code...or use a wildcard in FTP's interactive mode.

Comment: you mean to say first scan the dir to check how many files have to upload? and than take all files name into an array and put all ftp connection code into that block?

Comment: thank you so much, i have tried that and voilaa!! its working... but isn't it taking too long? because establishing connection and than disconnection for an other file

Comment: Cool.  Yeah, it would probably be faster to avoid having to re-connect and re-login for each file.  If there is a way to send multiple files with a wildcard (asterisk), that would be faster.